# Sort Alphanumeric on Array of more than one column

Tags: javascript, sorting, alphanumeric

This function works great when done on one array:

```js
var stringArray = ['48AB1','48AB10','48AB101','48AB106','48AB108','48AB11','48AB111','48AB1117','48AB1138','48AB18','48AB2'];
var regex = /^([a-z]*)(\d*)/i;
function sortFn(a, b) {
  var _a = a.match(regex);
  var _b = b.match(regex);

  // if the alphabetic part of a is less than that of b => -1
  if (_a[1] < _b[1]) return -1;
  // if the alphabetic part of a is greater than that of b => 1
  if (_a[1] > _b[1]) return 1;

  // if the alphabetic parts are equal, check the number parts
  var _n = parseInt(_a[2]) - parseInt(_b[2]);
  if(_n == 0) // if the number parts are equal start a recursive test on the rest
      return sortFn(a.substr(_a[0].length), b.substr(_b[0].length));
  // else, just sort using the numbers parts
  return _n;
}


console.log(stringArray.sort(sortFn))
```

I have an array of multiple columns, but i only want to sort the array on the 1st column. How can i modify this code to push just the one column into the sort function? I am pulling the data from an SQL service and using it to populate a JQuery table. The data comes sorted by default in natural order (i.e. 48AB1,48AB10,48AB100, etc.)

I am novice at programming so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit:
Here is more info on how I am creating it all

```js
var attrs = []
const activate = () => {

    WyoArch.serverApi("QuerySites").then(sites => {
            // jqxGrid creation
            // --> reusable options to stylize grid
            let mixinGridOptions = mixin => new Object({},
                columns: mixin.columns,
                source: createJqxDataAdapter(mixin.source || [])
            })

        attrs = sites; 
        console.log(attrs)
        // --> sites
        pickers.site.jqxGrid = $("#curateExisting-sitePicker .picker-jqxGrid").jqxGrid(mixinGridOptions({
            source: sites,
            columns: [{
                    text: 'ID',
                    datafield: 'SiteID',
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name',
                    datafield: 'SiteName',
                    width: 150
                },
                {
                    text: 'Landowner',
                    datafield: 'LandOwner',
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    text: 'TWN',
                    datafield: 'TWN',
                    width: 80
                },
                {
                    text: 'RNG',
                    datafield: 'RNG',
                    width: 80
                },
                {
                    text: 'Section',
                    datafield: 'Section',
                    width: 80
                },
            ],
        }))
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of teh console log of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn61d.jpg)

Comment: Suppose you have `const 2dStringArray = [stringArray]`, simply `2dStringArray[0].sort(sortFn) `

Comment: Can you supply a relatively short set of inputs and the expected output?

Comment: I need to fill in a table that has 6 columns. The expected output would be that the table has the new sort applied by default. It would look like how the "Run Code Snippet" above would look

Comment: That snippet is a single-dimension array.  It's not clear enough what your six columns means.  (Does it look anything like the example in my answer?)

Comment: I'm afraid the additional code doesn't help much.  Are the values from the first part (`'48AB1','48AB10'`, etc.) somehow tied to those from the second part(`{text: 'ID', datafield: 'SiteID', width: 100}`, etc.)?  You wanted to sort on a particular column.  I try to answer that below, but only with a random-ish guess on what the data looks like and how that column is integrated with the rest.  Your additions don't really describe that.

Comment: Scott, yes those are the values for the SiteID column in the JQuery table i am pushing the data into. The SiteID is the column i would like that sort to be on when the application loads up. I will upload a console log of what the array looks like.

Comment: Thanks Scott for all the help!

Comment: Scott, That worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: older versions of this have been discarded after the comments here and in the question clarified the requirements.

---

After working through the question and updates to it, it seems like this will do what is requested.  The data is snipped from an image -- please post text, not images of text! -- and might not quite match what's happening.  This uses what is to me a function with the same behavior as the original, but somewhat simplified.

But the main point is that to wrap your `sortFn` so that it works on elements with the sort property in the `SiteID` field, you can just write a new comparator like this:

```
(a, b) => sortFn(a.SiteID, b.SiteID)
```

... and pass that to `table.sort()`.

```js
const regex = /^([a-z]*)(\d*)/i;

const sortFn = (a, b) => {
  if (a == '' && b == '') {return 0;}
  const [a0, a1, a2] = a.match(regex);
  const [b0, b1, b2] = b.match(regex);
  return a1 < b1 ? -1 : a1 > b1 ? 1 : a2 - b2 || sortFn(a.substr(a0.length), b.substr(b0.length)) 
}

const sortBySiteId = (a, b) => sortFn(a.SiteID, b.SiteID)

var table = [
  {SiteID: '1ABCTest', SiteName: 'App Testing RK', ContactID: 250},
  {SiteID: '1ABCTest', SiteName: 'App Testing',    ContactID: 250},
  {SiteID: '1Albany',  SiteName: 'RK Test',        ContactID: 56},
  {SiteID: '1BCDTest', SiteName: 'RK Test 2',      ContactID: 201},
  {SiteID: '1OFF',     SiteName: 'One OFF',        ContactID: 161},
  {SiteID: '24BH406',  SiteName: 'KOBOLD RANCH',   ContactID: 250},
  {SiteID: '42IN124',  SiteName: null,             ContactID: null},
  {SiteID: '42IN40',   SiteName: null,             ContactID: null},
  {SiteID: '42SV5',    SiteName: null,             ContactID: null},
  {SiteID: '42UN95',   SiteName: null,             ContactID: null},
  {SiteID: '48AB1',    SiteName: 'CHINA WALL',     ContactID: null},
  {SiteID: '48AB10',   SiteName: 'EL PRIMERO',     ContactID: null},
];

console.log(table.sort(sortBySiteId))
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i try that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Comment: Are you getting that error in the console here (which would be strange as I don't) or in your own code?

Comment: In my own code. Scott, I have updated the question above to show more of what i am doing. It is missing a lot of code but that is the guts.

Comment: I still get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" error.

Comment: Scott, i am now getting a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error that just started showing up. do you have any ideas what that may be?

Comment: I'm guessing you will need to add some error checking.  That code assumes that the data is in the given format: blocks of letters interspersed with blocks of digits.  If there are items in your array without the `SiteId` property or with one that's not in that format, you will need to do some more massaging of the parameters to the comparator.  It shouldn't be hard, something like this might do it: `const sortBySiteId = (a, b) => sortFn((a.SiteID || '').replace(/\W/g, ''), (b.SiteID || '').replace(/\W/g, ''))`.

Comment: Thanks i will check into that!